# Word for a person who is responsible for their job and doesn't neglect it

Tags: single-word-requests, formality

This is a topic for a TOEFL essay:

> What are some important qualities of a good supervisor (boss)?

Now I'm looking for a word that best describes a supervisor that doesn't neglect their work, and success really matters to them. So they force their employees to do their job well.

Is there a good word that fits for this personality of good supervisors?

Comment: The supervisor is dedicated.

Comment: One could say that a good supervisor encourages and motivates their employees to perform well - that they do not need to force them to do their job well. :-)

Comment: That supervisor seems like pushy. Forcing does not sound like a positive action. Are you asking something like "positively pushy"?

Comment: Also, your title suggests a more general trait but your example includes leadership skills also. Do you want a general trait of any employee or worker, or just pertaining to a leader/manager? I would suggest you to modify the title then. So you can say "a supervisor/manager" instead of "a person".

Answer (score 2):

**Conscientious** (from the word conscience), defined by Google as *(of a person) wishing to do what is right, especially to do one's work or duty well and thoroughly.*

Answer (score 0):

I think [committed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/committed) may suggest the qualities described. (from www.dictionary.cambridge)

> - loyal and willing to give your time and energy to something that you believe in.

Answer (score 0):

How about diligent and motivational?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include leadership traits, as your example suggests, I would consider the adjective ***managerial***.

It can be used both for a person (e.g. managerial leader) or the skills of that person (e.g. managerial skills). Though, it can be used to describe the position also. (e.g. managerial role)

---

*Managerial skill* is defined as:

> the ability to make business decisions and lead subordinates within a company. Three most common skills include: 1) human skills - the ability to interact and motivate; 2) technical skills - the knowledge and proficiency in the trade; and 3) conceptual skills - the ability to understand concepts, develop ideas and implement strategies. Competencies include communication ability, response behavior and negotiation tactics.
>
> <sup>http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/managerial-skill.html</sup>

Below is a passage from an article that talks about the characteristics of a managerial leader along with other types of leadership (managerial vs. strategic vs. visionary). The article explains the positive traits of a managerial leader but also mentions their coercive behavior to keep things organized, and how they focus on short-term financial success.

> In short, managerial leaders need order and stability, and to be able to control the details of the work being performed. Mostly, these leaders have no personal attachment towards setting and using goals as motivational tools, and they may have difficulty showing empathy when dealing with employees. They will attempt to gain control through systems of rewards, punishment, and other forms of coercion. These leader/managers will be focused on the cost-benefit analysis of everyday actions and will therefore be mostly linked to the short-term financial health of the organization, as reflected in its day-to-day stock price. It is important to note that short-term gains are often a result of a least-cost approach, which might not be good for long-term viability.
>
> <sup>http://iveybusinessjournal.com/topics/leadership/strategic-leadership-short-term-stability-and-long-term-viability#.VEp8b_VvB8E</sup>

This article is fair enough that it talks about both positive and negative characteristics of different leadership styles. But in my opinion, managerial fits best for your example. Below is an explanatory graph from the same article:

[image]